# A value from one thread influencing the path of another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, server

I have a program which uses two client threads and a server. There is a point in my program where I want a value in one thread to influence the path of another thread.

More specifically, I have this code in the server:

```
class Handler 
{
    public void clientInteraction(Socket connection, bool isFirstThread, Barrier barrier)

    {
        string pAnswer = string.Empty;
        string endGameTrigger = string.Empty;
        //setup streamReaders and streamWriters

        while(true) //infinite game loop
        {
            //read in a question and send to both threads.
            pAnswer = sr.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(pAnswer);

            awardPoints(); 

            writeToConsole("Press ENTER to ask another question or enter 0 to end the game", isFirstThread);
            if(isFirstThread == true)
            {
                endGameTrigger = Console.ReadLine(); //this is only assigning to one thread...
            }

            barrier.SignalAndWait();

            if(endGameTrigger == "0")//...meaning this is never satisfied in one thread
            {
                endGame();
            }           

        }
    }
}
```

The boolean value `isFirstThread` is a value set up in the constructor of the thread to which I can detect which thread was connected first.

Is there some way, or perhaps a threading method, that will allow the second connected thread to detect that the `endGameTrigger` in the first thread has been set and therefore both threads execute the `endGame()` method properly.

Comment: Make it a field instead of a local. You'll also need to add synchronization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's best to be concerned with multithreading

- If it's absolutely necessary to start a separate thread for performance/UI reasons
- If your code may be running in a multithreaded environment (like a web site) and you need to know that it won't break when multiple threads operate on the same class or same values.

But exercise extreme caution. Incorrect use/handling of multiple threads can cause your code to behave unpredictably and inconsistently. Something will work most of the time and then not work for no apparent reason. Bugs will be difficult to reproduce and identify.

That being said, one of the essential concepts of handling multithreading is to ensure that two threads don't try to update the same value at the same time. They can corrupt or partially modify values in ways that would be impossible for a single thread.

One way to accomplish this is with [locking](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

```
private object _lockObject = new Object();
private string _myString;

void SetStringValue(string newValue)
{
    lock(_lockObject)
    {
        _myString = newValue;
    }
}
```

You generally have an object that exists only to serve as a lock. When one thread enters that `lock` block it acquires a lock on the object. If another thread already has a lock on that object then the next thread just waits for the previous thread to release the lock. That ensures that two threads can't update the value at the same time.

You want to keep the amount of code inside the `lock` as small as possible so that the lock is released as soon as possible. And be aware that if it gets complicated with multiple locks then two threads can permanently block each other.

For incrementing and updating numbers there are also [interlocked operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbhbke0y(v=vs.110).aspx) that handle the locking for you, ensuring that those operations are executed by one thread at a time.

Just for fun I wrote this console app. It takes a sentence, breaks it into words, and then adds each word back onto a new string using multiple threads and outputs the string.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FunWithThreading
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var sentence =
                "I am going to add each of these words to a string "
                + "using multiple threads just to see what happens.";
            var words = sentence.Split(' ');
            var output = "";
            Parallel.ForEach(words, word => output = output + " " + word);
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The first two times I ran it, the output string was exactly what I started with. Great, it works perfectly! Then I got this:

`I am going to add of these words to a string using multiple threads just to see what happens. each`

Then I ran it 20 more times and couldn't repeat the error. Just imagine the frustration if this was a real application and something unpredictable like this happened even though I tested over and over and over, and then I couldn't get it to happen again.

So the point isn't that multithreading is evil, but just to understand the risks, only introduce it if you need to, and then carefully consider how to prevent threads from interfering with each other.

Answer (score 0):

In response to Luaan's comment. I have put the `endGameTrigger` as `private static string endGameTrigger` in the Handler class. Making it a `static` field instead of a local method variable allows all instances of the `handler` class (each thread) access to this variable's most recent assignation. Many thanks.

Comment: See my comment - you don't want multiple threads modifying the same string (or other value) unless you use a lock to make sure that they don't attempt to modify it at the exact same time. Weird, unpredictable, inconsistent things can and will happen.

Comment: My code will only ever be dealing with two threads at any one time, and only the first thread (identified by the boolean) will be operating on changing the value. The other thread will only ever access the variable to find the value, never to set a new one. So in this case, my answer is a fix.

Comment: that being said however! your input on locking is certainly interesting and unequivocably far better coding practice, and although I probably don't need to, I'm looking into locking now. Many thanks for alerting me to this problem.

Comment: It doesn't matter that one thread reads while the other writes. One could read while the other is writing. The fix will work most of the time, but then it won't. There are things going on behind the scenes that we don't know or think about, and they don't affect us as long as our operations are single-threaded. That's why even if the application is multithreaded we need to be sure that certain parts of our code, like reading and writing a single string, are single-threaded.