# Multithreading matrix multiplication in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, matrix

I have a task - write multithreading matrix multiplication. Each vector product must be calculated in new thread.(If we have matrices n by m and m by k we must have n by k threads). Also I must show order of calculation for elements of result matrix. I wrote code and got strange result - order of calculation is almost sequentially. But I calculate each element in new thread, so I must get random order of calculation for elements of the result matrix. What is wrong? This is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MatrixMultiplication
{
class Matrix
{
    public int Row{get; set;}
    public int Column { get; set;}
    double[,] arr;
    Matrix() { }
    public Matrix(int row,int column)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
        arr = new double[row, column];
    }
    public double[] GetColumn(int i)
    {
        double[] res=new double[Row];
        for (int j = 0; j < Row; j++)
            res[j] = arr[j, i];
        return res;
    }
    public double[] GetRow(int i)
    {
        double[] res = new double[Column];
        for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
            res[j] = arr[i, j];
        return res;
    }
    public double this[int i,int j]
    {
        get { return arr[i, j]; }
        set { arr[i, j] = value; }
    }
    public Matrix RandomValues()
    {
        Random rnd=new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
                arr[i, j] =rnd.Next(10);
        return this;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<Row;i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
                Console.Write(arr[i,j]+" ");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public static Matrix operator*(Matrix a, Matrix b)
    {
        Matrix result=new Matrix(a.Row,b.Column);
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        for (int i = 0; i <a.Row*b.Column;i++ )
        {
            int tempi = i; 
            Thread thread = new Thread(()=>VectorMult(tempi, a, b, result));
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }
        foreach (Thread t in threads)
            t.Join();
        return result;
    }

    public  static void VectorMult(int tmp, Matrix a, Matrix b,Matrix result){
        int i = tmp / b.Column;
        int j = tmp % b.Column;
        double[] x = a.GetRow(i);
        double[] y = b.GetColumn(j);
        for (int k = 0; k < x.Length; k++)
            result[i, j] += x[k] * y[k];
        Console.WriteLine("Calculate element{0}{1}", i, j);
    }
  }

  class Program
  {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
         Matrix A = new Matrix(n,m).RandomValues();
         Matrix B = new Matrix(m,k).RandomValues();
         A.Print();
         Console.WriteLine(new String('-',20));
         B.Print();
         Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
         Matrix C = A * B;
         C.Print();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please check out your coursework notes. Code as shown does not demonstrate usage of any synchronization primitives which most likely should be present to get passing grade (and definitely must if one actually cares to get correct result).

Comment: Great improvements can be made by using jagged arrays. Change `double[,] arr;` to `double[][] arr;` and modify the code accordingly. Now each row `arr[i]` is an array the can be processes independently

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is normal - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36376590/a-value-from-one-thread-influencing-the-path-of-another-thread/36377029#36377029) from earlier today which demonstrates how processes in separate threads don't always operate in the expected sequence. They might do so much or most of the time, but then you get some unexpected behavior.

Do the calculations need to occur in a specific sequence, or do you just need to be able to see the sequence in which they occurred?

If you're starting new threads then it's impossible to control the sequence. (You've already seen that.) You also can't capture the order in which they were completed, because completion of a calculation and recording the result (the console or any other output) isn't an atomic operation.

This could happen:

1. Calculation A finishes
2. Calculation B finishes
3. Calculation B is recorded
4. Calculation A is recorded

Multithreading isn't great when operations have to occur in a specific sequence.

You can insert the results of your calculation into a `ConcurrentQueue` as they are completed, and the sequence will be *mostly* correct.

Comment: I need to see order in which calculated threads. And I get input almost equal input in program without mutlithreading(I print on screen number of element of result matrix). But I think that elements of result matrix should be calculated in random order.

Comment: To make sure I understand - are you saying that the order of calculations might be random or that you want to make it random?

Comment: I want to make it random. But I think when I calculate elements of resulting matrix in different threads order of calculation must be random by default. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should keep your code as simple and explicit as possible.
Instead of calculating `i < a.Row * b.Column` you should have made 2 ***for***s:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Row; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < b.Column; j++)
    {
        int tempi = i;
        int tempj = j;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() => VectorMult(tempi, tempj, a, b, result));
        thread.Start();
        threads.Add(thread);
    }
```

And then, in the `VectorMult(int tmpi, int tmpj, Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix result)` function, instead of calculating that `j = tempi % b.Column` stuff, you give as parameter ***tempj***. Having ***i*** and ***j*** it becomes:

```
int i = tmpi;
int j = tmpj;
double[] x = a.GetRow(i);
double[] y = b.GetColumn(j);
for (int k = 0; k < x.Length; k++)
    result[i, j] += x[k] * y[k];
```

Finally, don't forget that when working with shared resources and threads, things can go pretty crazy. Make sure you use Mutexes.

Here you have my whole code,

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MatrixMultiplication
{
    class Matrix
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public int Column { get; set; }
        double[,] arr;
        public static Mutex mutex = new Mutex();

        Matrix() { }
        public Matrix(int row, int column)
        {
            Row = row;
            Column = column;
            arr = new double[row, column];
        }
        public double[] GetColumn(int i)
        {
            double[] res = new double[Row];
            for (int j = 0; j < Row; j++)
                res[j] = arr[j, i];
            return res;
        }
        public double[] GetRow(int i)
        {
            double[] res = new double[Column];
            for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
                res[j] = arr[i, j];
            return res;
        }
        public double this[int i, int j]
        {
            get { return arr[i, j]; }
            set { arr[i, j] = value; }
        }
        public Matrix RandomValues()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
                    arr[i, j] = rnd.Next(10);
            return this;
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Row; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < Column; j++)
                    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        public static Matrix operator *(Matrix a, Matrix b)
        {
            Matrix result = new Matrix(a.Row, b.Column);
            List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Row; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j < b.Column; j++)
                {
                    int tempi = i;
                    int tempj = j;
                    Thread thread = new Thread(() => VectorMult(tempi, tempj, a, b, result));
                    thread.Start();
                    threads.Add(thread);
                }
            foreach (Thread t in threads)
                t.Join();
            return result;
        }

        public static void VectorMult(int tmpi, int tmpj, Matrix a, Matrix b, Matrix result)
        {
            mutex.WaitOne();
            int i = tmpi;
            int j = tmpj;
            double[] x = a.GetRow(i);
            double[] y = b.GetColumn(j);

            for (int k = 0; k < x.Length; k++)
                result[i, j] += x[k] * y[k];

            mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("n=");
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("m=");
            int m = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("k=");
            int k = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Matrix A = new Matrix(n, m).RandomValues();
            Matrix B = new Matrix(m, k).RandomValues();
            A.Print();
            Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
            B.Print();
            Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 20));
            Matrix C = A * B;
            C.Print();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Wish you all the best! :)